# Can i set variable as the initalization style after initalization? C#

Tags: c#

I can do this

```
var v = new class_name() { media_id = m, fn = fullfn2 };
```

Can i do something like this

```
set v { media_id = m, fn = fullfn2 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This syntax is only for initialization.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can do this

```
var v = new { media_id = m, fn = fullfn2 };
```

Comment: FWIW I think that's what he meant is his top example. He's asking to *change* the variables, once set, one a given object.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET you can, with the `with` keyword (I believe).

But what you're trying to do seems really horrible. Just set them explicitly. It's almost exactly the same amount of code.

Comment: cant, i am actually doing var v = GetDeriveType(config); which gives me an default object. I need to set the values outside of init and instead of inside multiple places.

Comment: @acidzombie24: So you can't change them from outside the type? Yet you can set them in the constructor? And want to be able to change them once the constructor has run? It seems all kinds of wrong to me (the design). See, this is the classical problem with having a feature-rich language; people abuse it. *sigh*

Comment: i think you misread my comment. I CAN set them outside, i cant set them inside unless i want to do it in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler says no.

---

But you can do all sorts of weird things like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo f = new Foo { Bar = 1, Name = "1" };

    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", f.Bar, f.Name);

    Action<Foo> set = (Foo foo) => { foo.Bar = 2; foo.Name = "2"; };

    set(f);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", f.Bar, f.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote on the initial answer, but a simple question deserves a simple answer.

Comment: I did it, i downvoted because i know the original way 'the compiler says no'. I wanted to know some way to do it in that syntax (or alike). (I'll remove the downvote since you tried)

Comment: btw most of my answers are pretty short as well.